# How to change location of my location button in google maps using swift

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, currentlocation

[image: my location button]

I am using google maps in my project i want to show my location button
a bit up how should i do that using swift

Comment: @ Amma teja :- I don't think you can change the position of my location button, but what you can do is, create your own button and give it whatever frame you want.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can change the position of the [MapControls](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/controls) by set the padding for your map view .

```
 let mapView = GMSMapView()

 mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
 mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true

 mapView.padding = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 50, right: 50)
```

*It will change the padding of the my location control. From bottom 50px and from right 50px*

Refer the below screenshot which added the padding of 50px from bottom and right.

[image]

Comment: but as you can see the position of current location also shift, but I want to keep the current location centre while moving the **myLocationButton** upward. How can I do that please ?

Comment: @subramanian: have small doubt here, i want to change the position of my location button only. not "Google" text also

Comment: For this once you change the location button and press the button ,current location will not come on centre.

Comment: How to enable map toolbar... ?

Comment: can we hide this button ?

Answer (score 7):

Update for swift 4 : just change the position of my location button only

```
for object in self.mapView.subviews{
            if(object.theClassName == "GMSUISettingsPaddingView"){
                for view in object.subviews{
                    if(view.theClassName == "GMSUISettingsView"){
                        for btn in view.subviews{
                            if(btn.theClassName == "GMSx_QTMButton"){
                                var frame = btn.frame
                                frame.origin.y = frame.origin.y - 100
                                btn.frame = frame

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    public extension NSObject {
    public var theClassName: String {
        return NSStringFromClass(type(of: self))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Like Subramanian, this works very well :

```
mapView.padding = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 50, right: 0)
```

This is perfect if you have a navigation bar in your app.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my function for Google Maps SDK 5.1.0, since the button's class was renamed to 'GMSx_MDCFloatingButton' in case someone needs an updated approach.

Also depending on your implementation you might want to call this on viewDidAppear().

```
func moveLocationButton(){
        for object in self.googleMapsView!.subviews{
            if(object.thisClassName == "GMSUISettingsPaddingView"){
                for view in object.subviews{
                    if(view.thisClassName == "GMSUISettingsView"){
                        for btn in view.subviews{
                            if(btn.theClassName == "GMSx_MDCFloatingButton"){
                                var frame = btn.frame
                                frame.origin.x = frame.origin.x - 50
                                frame.origin.y = frame.origin.y - 150
                                btn.frame = frame
                                
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public extension NSObject {
    var thisClassName: String {
        return NSStringFromClass(type(of: self))
       }
    }
```

Comment: Calling it on "viewDidAppear" will cause the button to jump. So I called this in "viewDidLoad" with a slight delay: "DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1)"

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to change button position by correcting constraint instead of changing `frame.origin`. I got it worked by changing `frame.origin` placing it into `viewDidAppear` only. Neither `viewWillApper` nor `viewWillLayoutSubviews` were correct methods to call from. However I managed it work perfectly calling constraint changing from `viewDidLoad`. And I used snapkit, but it is not a big deal to get it done natively

```
private func changeCurrentLocationButtonPosition(of mapView: GMSMapView) {
    for object in mapView.subviews where object.theClassName == "GMSUISettingsPaddingView" {
        for view in object.subviews where view.theClassName == "GMSUISettingsView" {
            for btn in view.subviews where btn.theClassName == "GMSx_MDCFloatingButton" {
                btn.snp.makeConstraints({ maker in
                    maker.left.equalToSuperview().offset(15)
                })
                btn.snp.makeConstraints({ maker in
                    maker.bottom.equalToSuperview().offset(-30)
                })
                return
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this function and call this at **viewDidLayoutSubviews()**

```
func changeLocationBtnFrame(){
    self.mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
    for obj in self.mapView.subviews{
        if String(describing: obj.classForCoder) == "GMSUISettingsPaddingView"{
            for viw in obj.subviews{
                if String(describing: viw.classForCoder) == "GMSUISettingsView"{
                    for btn in viw.subviews{
                        if String(describing: btn.classForCoder) == "GMSx_MDCFloatingButton"{
                            var frame = btn.frame
                            
                            btn.frame = CGRect(x: 316, y: 0, width: 56, height: 56)
                            //USE you want frame this line
                            break
                        }
                    }
                    break
                }
            }
            break
        }
    }
}
```